# TSQL Query Statement in DAX for Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

I am trying to count all rows in a table in Power BI which uses a Where condition.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Hoping you can help me out. Here is the TSQL Syntax and the results I want. When I execute the DAX query, I get nothing.

I need the DAX statement to work the same and generate the same results. I have been successful at using NOT IN in DAX, but for some reason, I am missing something for the IN clause.

TSQL:

```
SELECT Closed_Date
     , Closed_By
     , Count(*) CompletedTicket_By_Date
FROM Planning.dbo.IT_Support_Ticket
Where Status In ('Complete', 'Closed', 'Cancelled')
Group By Closed_Date
       , Closed_By
```

DAX:

```
Ticket Closed Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fact_IT_Support_Ticket)
,FILTER(Fact_IT_Support_Ticket, Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status]="Closed"),
Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status]="Complete", 
Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status]="Cancelled")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using only one filter expression with multiple conditions using the `OR` operator `||`.

```
Ticket Closed Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Fact_IT_Support_Ticket ),
    FILTER (
        Fact_IT_Support_Ticket,
        Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status] = "Closed"
            || Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status] = "Complete"
            || Fact_IT_Support_Ticket[Status] = "Cancelled"
    )
)
```

As said in documentation the second argument of the filter function is a boolean expression that is evaluated per row. Note the expression above evaluates if every value in the Status column is `Complete`, `Closed`, `Cancelled`. The `COUNTROWS` function counts only the filtered rows in the given context.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634966.aspx)

I've not tested the solution but it should work, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Exactly what I needed!!